# How to send a post request to a specific URI from PowerApps?

Tags: http, post, base64, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am looking for a way to send a post request to a specific URI from PowerApps.

Basically I have a small audio file (webm) captured from the microphone and it's encoded using Base64. Now I have to send it to a server via post request and the encoded data should be put in the body of the request, since it is too big (for Nginx) to be put in the URL itself (?data=).

Can I achieve it in PowerApps?

## Binary to encoded text (in PowerApps):

```
Set(BinaryAudioData_2, Substitute(JSON(Mic2.Audio,JSONFormat.IncludeBinaryData),"""","")); 
Set(AudioFile, Mic2.Audio); Collect(Collection3, AudioFile);
```

Comment: any follow up questions?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a Power Automate Flow from PowerApps, then Flow can target the specific URI. [Read more](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-from-powerapps-using-flow/)

[image]